# Embeded page for pagelayout does not work in apex:detail

Tags: inline, force.com-embedded

I put visualforce page as into pagelayout for opportunity (embeded page ). For show my problem, I created next visualforce page

```
<apex:page standardController="opportunity">
<apex:form >

   <apex:detail subject="{!opportunity.id}" relatedList="false" inlineEdit="true"/>

   <apex:detail subject="{!opportunity.id}" relatedList="false" inlineEdit="true"/>

</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

If I go on this page, I see embedded page only for first apex:detail section, for second not. If I edited some field in second apex:detail section, the second section is reloaded, what is correct, but embedded page from the first apex:detail section is reloaded (why from first section, if I edited second?).

this is only easy example, in real page I do not show the same opportunity, but behavior is the same.

Comment: I just tried to reproduce your problem starting from your page and also using some different ids and the behaviour seemed pretty reasonable for both the inline edit case and when the edit button is used.